# how to count the number of values in a specific key in a python defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to complete this question. I don't know where I'm going wrong..

> First line of the input is a number, which indicates how many pairs of
>   words will follow (each pair in a separate line). The pairs are of the
>   form COUNTRY CITY specifying in which country a city is located. The
>   last line is the name of a city. Print the number of cities that are
>   located in the same country as this city.
>
> Hint. Use dictionaries.

For example, on input:

```
6
UK London
US Boston
UK Manchester
UK Leeds
US Dallas
Russia Moscow
Manchester
```

output must be:
3

```
from collections import defaultdict

n=input()
d=defaultdict(list)
city=' '



 for i in range(0,int(n)):
  kv=input().split()
  d[kv[0]].append(kv[1])




 for k1,v1 in d.items():
 if v1==city:
   print(len(k1))
```

Comment: city is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing the input of the city
And you need to check if the city is in the list, and just then count how many there are

```py
from collections import defaultdict

n=input()
d=defaultdict(list)
city=' '



for i in range(0,int(n)):
  kv=input().split()
  d[kv[0]].append(kv[1])



city = input('Enter a city')
for k1,v1 in d.items():
 if city in v1:
   print(len(v1))
```

Comment: @ALISAHIN No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, you need to take input for the query city as well. And additionally you can approach this a bit differently - you don't need `defaultdict`. Since your query is a city, let's store that as the key in the dictionary, with the value being the country. Then we can find which country we need to get. After than it's just a matter of counting up the values of that country in the dictionary.

```
n = input()
city_to_country = {}

for i in range(0, int(n)):
    kv = input().split()
    city_to_country[kv[1].rstrip()] = kv[0]

query_city = input()

target_country = city_to_country[query_city]

print(list(city_to_country.values()).count(target_country))
```